# Shell script to take multiple user input in single file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

A shell script should take multiple condition in single line input and it should take one end of input character to perform next operation. ie.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Functions are defined here 1 2 3 4 5


echo "choice"
echo 
echo "[1] one"
echo "[2] two"
echo "[3] three"
echo "[4] four"
echo "[5] five"
echo
read -p "Enter choice:  " ch
        if [ "$ch" = "1" ]; then
        function_1
        else
        if [ "$ch" = "2" ]; then
        function_2
        else
        if [ "$ch" = "3" ]; then
        function_3
        else
        if [ "$ch" = "4" ]; then
        function_4
        else
        if [ "$ch" = "5" ]; then
        function_5
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
```

now say end of input taking denoted by 'e' hence if I execute the .sh file and in "Enter choice"

```
$Enter choice: 1 3 5 e
```

it should execute 1 3 and 5th function one by one
how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over all the choices until you find the 'end of input':

```
read -p "Enter choice:  " ch

for choice in $ch; do
    [ "$choice" == 'e' ] && break
    eval function_$choice
done
```

NOTE: `eval` will assemble a command from the arguments and then execute it through the shell

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over your string ch until "e" appears:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Functions are defined here 1 2 3 4 5


echo "choice"
echo 
echo "[1] one"
echo "[2] two"
echo "[3] three"
echo "[4] four"
echo "[5] five"
echo
read -p "Enter choice:  " ch

for i in ${ch}
do
  if [ "$i" == "1" ]; then
    function_1
  else if [ "$i" == "2" ]; then
    function_2
  else if [ "$i" == "3" ]; then
    function_3
  else if [ "$i" == "4" ]; then
    function_4
  else if [ "$i" == "5" ]; then
    function_5
  else if [ "$i" == "e" ]; then
    break
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
```

but the answer of mxlian is "cleaner". i just corrent your code..

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you made each input parameter an option and used getopts ie

```
myProg.sh -a aArg -b bArg -c cArg
```

Inside myProg.sh:

```
while getopts "a:b:c" option
do
    case $option in
    a) function_1;;
    b) function_2;;
    c) function_3;;
    *) exitFunc "Incorrect argument";;   # You need to write exitFunc()
    esac
done
```

This way you can have a missing option ie only option a and c (no b). If you do it your way and one parameter is missing (or null) say paramater 3 then parameter 4 becomes parameter 3 etc.